# Why is Google Search Console crawling/discovering pages that do not exist?

Tags: google-search-console

I am working on a site to do with domestic cleaning. When I check on Google Search Console, the page indexing section advises that there are thousands of pages that are either crawled but not indexed or discovered but not indexed. When I try to look at them, all return 404 error.

Google console advises the source is Google System not website.

Have been onto my hosting (hosting24.com) who simply say the pages do not exist. All my other pages that should be indexed are. Is this something I should be worried about? Would it effect my ranking?

Comment: check your pages in URL Inspection tool  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en

Comment: Hi, have used this. Google advises this is a merchant listing. Upshot is that I want to remove these as they shouldn't be there. But cannot find them to delete them

Comment: 404 error pages don't really hurt your SEO, so you need not worry, You may consider to using 301 redirect to redirect bad backlinks to your home page... or simply redirect all the pages from backlink sites to home page or desired working page... or even you may consider block that sites

Answer (score 1):

404s in themselves are not an issue. Leave them to 404 if they really don't exist or never existed.

There is a chance that Googlebot picked up a lot of 404s due to some bad links on your site or around the internet. It's best to try and fix those links. The inspect tool may give you an example of what linked to a 404 page. Or you could run your own spider to see if it picks up links to missing pages.